# How call a cshtml view from a static html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I am using the Kool-swap plugin which allows for transitions when redirecting to new pages. When implementing the plugin in C# MVC 5, I can only make it work for static html pages but not cshtml pages.

how i can call w cshtml from a satic html page????

who know some valid href???

Comment: You can not directly call a cshtml page but you can send request to a controller that returns a cshtml. Tell us more about your problem.

Comment: Here for exemple, i want to call  the View  Index.cshtml  under TypeCompte Controller.In this simple html tag:  <div class="panel-body"><a href="????????????">Type Compte</a></div>

Comment: Unsure what you are saying, in `MVC` you "call a cshtml"  page just like any other "link" - you can even hard code (not that you should, but just stating to simplify): `<a href="/index">Home Page</a>` - this is what is rendered at the end of the day by some `Helper`

Comment: You have to put url of your controller action in href. for example href="/TypeCompte/Index"